# Laravel custom ModelNotFoundException handling per route group

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, routes

I have two route groups in my Laravel application, one for an API and one for the website itself. I've added the following code in `global.php` for error handling of my API.

```
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
   return Response::json('', 404);
});
```

But not this obviously also has effect on my normal website, where I want to return a normal view when the `ModelNotFoundException` occurs. Like so:

```
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
   return Response::view('404.html', [], 404);
});
```

How can I setup different error handlers for different route groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't care what part of the site that threw the error, but instead respond with whatever format the client *requested*.  In general this is set in the `Accepts` header of the request and can be accessed in Laravel by:

```
if (Request::format() == 'json')
{
    //
}
```

(above is taken from the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#request-information))

In your case, this would turn your error handling function to this:

```
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
   if (Request::format() == 'json') {
       return Response::json('', 404);
   } else {
       return Response::view('404.html', [], 404);
   }
});
```

This automatically covers you if, for instance, you add an non-API AJAX request to the main portion of your website (for whatever reason) that could potentially trigger a `ModelNotFoundException`.  As long as your client sends the appropriate request headers, you're good.

Comment: Yes, I agree, this is the better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try with changing environment. For selected group you could change environment using:

```
$app->setEnvironment('enviromentname');
```

and create new `environmentname.php` file in `start` directory

But I don't know if it will work.

You could also create a session variable and in `App:error` add code depending on this session variable:

```
   $value = Session::get('type');

  if ($value == 'onetype') {
     // something
  }
  else {
    // something else
  }
```